# Changing java build location in VSCode (code-runner)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compilation, vscode-code-runner

Hopefully a simple question with a simple answer! All I'm trying to do is separate a .java and .class files; I'm compiling using code-runner and have not found a way to change the default build location (same folder as .java files). I've tried searching a few keywords in the settings.json, as well as looked through the preferences/settings, but I haven't found anything useful.

Would appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to disable the code-runner, instead of use the "java: force java compilation" command(Ctrl+Shift+P), then the vscode will help you compile the .java file automatically, and location the .class file in the satisfied place. as the code-runner just place the .class files alongside the .java files.